# What's the maximum text message size of WebSocketSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, size, message

I would like to know: What's the maximum text message size of WebSocketSharp?
If a message string exceeds the max size, will it be split into small chunks of data, and sent to server side over websocket?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/WebSocket.cs) there seems to be no maximum size. There is an internal field `FragmentLength` with the following comment

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the length used to determine whether the data should be fragmented in sending.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///   <para>
///   The data will be fragmented if that length is greater than the value of this field.
///   </para>
///   <para>
///   If you would like to change the value, you must set it to a value between <c>125</c> and
///   <c>Int32.MaxValue - 14</c> inclusive.
///   </para>
/// </remarks>
```

Comment: So when we implement the receiveasync, we can create the buffer with any size , and the message sent from client over websocket would be split into chunks according to the buffer size, right?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think the mentioned field is initialized to 1016 which is the size of chunks. Just check the source by searching for ja fieldname.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Not sure if you ever use WebSocket library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket.receiveasync?view=netframework-4.7.2, I find websocket-sharp has some unreliable issues, and not updated for some time. So I am thinking of implementing websocket client and server separately with websocket library again. 
So what's the chunk size of data? I see the ReceiveAsync will split the data into chunks based on buffer size we setup, am I right?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is wrong to say that WebSocket has some maximum length of messages. There is some [buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocketoptions.setbuffer?view=net-5.0) and if your message will be more than it, you will get your message by parts. But only the last part will have [EndOfMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocketreceiveresult.endofmessage?view=net-5.0)=true.

Comment: Thank you, actually I am asking the question about the sdk: websocket-sharp,https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocketSharp/1.0.3-rc11
Regarding what you mentioned, I assume the chunks/fragments of message don't conform the object json deserialization.

Comment: I don't know how exactly works this package, but I think that object deserialization inside it will be done when all of the chunks will be received.

Answer (score -2):

I think the appropriate way is to ask this question directly on github https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp

Comment: Good, I just find that document is very quiet.

Comment: indeed you're right, but the discussion should be leaded in the issue area of the project, in fact also here ;-)
edit: the issue are seems, like it's not that good maintained